# dynamic provider options through app config AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have provider modules that accept configurations like:

```
angular.module('app', ['search']).
  config(['$searchProvider', function($searchProvider) {
    $searchProvider.options({
      resultLimit:50,
      defaultSort:'highToLow'
    });
  }]);
```

There will be a new app instantiation per client --- so I am thinking about using a client self serve portal to configure `meta` object.

This means the provider modules now need to sit inside a callback method to wait for `meta` before they can set their respective configurations.

But let's all remember: **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured...

...So the docs say you can use provider in configuration blocks, but I'm not sure you can use them to make service calls. Because I have no idea how to handle this the right way, I will show you my "high level" idea:

**Wrap dependant providers with another provider callback:**

```
angular.module('app', ['search','meta']).
  config(['$searchProvider','$metaProvider', function($searchProvider, $metaProvider) {
    $metaProvider.get(function(meta){
      $searchProvider.options(meta);
    });
  }]);
```

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Can't you just dump the config in JSON on page load from your server-side language of choice?

Comment: @JaniHartikainen Single Page App. There is none.

Comment: If your providers are waiting for async data like @JaniHartikainen pointed out, than you should really consider bootstrapping that data into the html. On the other hand, if your user can wait for your app to be fully configured, than you can manually bootstrap angular. There is no way of re-configuring providers after the app has been bootstrapped. I am just curious - why don't you use plain services instead of providers ?

Comment: @g00fy The providers are modules that contain several methods. There are several custom configurations. At this point I am thinking of wrapping them in a callback function inside my app level controller. Instantiating them has little cost/overhead where the API calls can be made later at the child controller level as needed.

Comment: @DanKanze do you want your providers to be async ? I am guessing that if you are using callbacks, than yes. The only problem here, is that providers should be sync, because you need to configure your app before you can actually run it. It makes much sense this way.

Comment: @g00fy Yea you are right --- controllers wont be able to scope provider methods/data because they wont be configured yet from the callback. I have no idea how I'm going to solve this problem working within the confines of the framework. If you have a solution that can bootstrap angular client side I would really like to see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. I couldn't find a solution to work within the bounds of the framework so I worked around the problem by manually bootstrapping angular after I have loaded all of the client configuration information. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap

```
$.get('/api/context', function () {
    // ...
    angular.bootstrap($('#container'), ['app']);
});
```

Comment: `$.get` isnt available though angular's global API is it? I would have to include jquery or roll my own xhr to make a GET request right?