# Angularjs: Good way to configure callbacks which use services in providers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to configure callbacks inside of an angularjs-provider.

```
myApp.config(function(SomeProvider) {
    SomeProvider.defaultCallback = function(foo, bar) {
        console.log("foo: " + foo + ", bar: " + bar);
    }
})
```

The Problem is, I want to use services in this callbacks. In this example I would like to use `$log.log` instead of `console.log`.

I cannot inject all this services in my config block, because they don't exist yet.

**The question is, how do I use services in this cofigurable callbacks?**

Comment: You can't use providers in config block ... The best thing is to use them in run block

Comment: I hope you mean services or I don't understand. You cannot inject Providers in a run-block so you cannot configure them there. It would also be too late, because you would allready have injected the unconfigured service

Comment: Yeah i mean services. You can only inject provider and constant in config block

Comment: I know, thats the reason for this question. I need them inside of my callback. Not directly in the config block.

Comment: Yeah but your callback is in your config block .. What's the difference ? How you get your service without inject it ? IMHO you can't do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution:

You must have the $injector available to do this. Therefore everytime the callback is called, the $injector must be passed in:

```
myApp.config(function(SomeProvider) {
    SomeProvider.defaultCallback = function(foo, bar, $injector) {
        var $log = $injector.get("$log");
        $log.log("foo: " + foo + ", bar: " + bar);
    }
})


// ... callbacks will be called this way:
myObject.theCallback(foo, bar, $injector);
```

Comment: Anyway it's a pretty thing :)

Comment: As far as I know, manual injection is not a huge problem. It is still possible to use mocked services in tests in the same way like with automatic injection.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had this problem too and found a more elegant solution which might help someone. Note my examples are written in coffeescript.

maklemenz is right about using the `$injector` service, but it should stay hidden in your provider code instead:

```
angular.module("myModule").provider "myService", () ->

  defaultCallback = () ->
  this.setDefaultCallback = (callback) ->
    defaultCallback = 

  this.$get = ["$injector", ($injector) -> {
    #...service code...

      #when you want to invoke your callback:
      $injector.invoke defaultCallback

    #...more service code...
  }]

  return this
```

The main advantage of this approach is that you can use any of the normal angular injection notations in your callback:

```
#using implicit injection (not minification-safe!)
angular.module("myApp").config (myServiceProvider) ->

  myServiceProvider.setDefaultCallback ($log) ->
    $log.log "some message"
```

This is the simplest use of the `$injector.invoke` method. It provides a great deal of flexibilty so it's well worth checking out the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this post : [dynamic provider options through app config AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557088/dynamic-provider-options-through-app-config-angularjs)

Like i said in comments IMHO you can't use service in config block (in callback or not)..

The solution in this thread is to use the JQuery API to make the call and then bootstrap angular...

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where I needed a particular service in a callback in a config block, but I didn't have access to the callback provider. I found that injecting the $injector into the config block itself doesn't work as it isn't guaranteed to have setup the service and rather peculiarly you seem get the $injector state from when the config ran rather than when the callback is called. Given that I couldn't change the actual callback to always directly inject $injector, the only way I could get it to work was to grab the injector from the dom. So you end up with something like this (note the ES6 class stylings!)...

```
class AppAuth {
static configure($authProvider) {


    $authProvider.configure({
        apiUrl: '',
        handleAccountUpdateResponse: (response) => {
        const injector = angular.element(document.getElementById('app')).injector();
        const Client = injector.get('Client');
        response.data.clients.forEach((client, index, clients) => {
           clients[index] = new Client(client);
          });
        return response;
        }
    })
  }
}

export default AppAuth
```

A tad hacky, but the requirement is fairly standard, I am wrapping associated records (the clients in the example) with a local model wrapper (Client). The library (ng-token-auth) sets the callback in the config block and wants a straight function with one parameter, no ability to pass in a $injector. Hope that helps someone with a similar situation.