# add third party module in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I need a third party module in my angular app for the specific page only so i dont want to load those js files when they are not required

currently code is like this

```
angular.module('app', ['othermodule']);
```

but i want it like

```
angular.module('app',['']).
controller('ctrl'['module',function(module){

}]);
```

or any similar alternatives. How can modules be loaded conditionally ?

Comment: [Developing an AngularJS app with dynamic set of modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806901/developing-an-angularjs-app-with-dynamic-set-of-modules?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need to do is break your angular modules out into their own files. A simple example would be a seperate app.js that handles creating the app and routing, then controller.js and factory.js. Once you have a seperate file for each module you create the module with this syntax

```
angular.module('myapp.functionName.type',  ['inject your custom module here'])
.whatever (controller, value, factory, etc)
```

You would then inject the myapp.functionName.type into the app.js

Comment: i think you didnt undertand my question. I am already doing that. So for `angular.module('myapp.functionName.type',  ['inject your custom module here'])`. you need to load custom modules along with main app. I want to load these custom module condtionally.